# Don't show multiple records in SQL Query

Tags: select

I have a table called `test_series_records` Where users can give their test, They can give the test multiple times. Now I want to show all the records that given at the last. In example:

Table has record like this:

[image: Table Image with the data]

As you can see the `506900` and `506901` id's are the same user. I want the result with the `506901` id because it's created last time. Similarly I want all the records has last id or Max id but not multple entries. How can I achive that?

I have tried this:

```
SELECT TRUNCATE id, user_id, test_id, total_questions, correct_answers, wrong_answers, skipped_answers, test_time, time_taken FROM `test_series_records` WHERE `test_id` = 62;
```

Comment: I think you need to use group by id and having clause like having with MAX function I hope it will help full you

Comment: What does `SELECT TRUNCATE`  do?  What else did you try to resolve your problem?

Comment: Can you please write it for me? @SachinSarola

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope this will help you the inner query will get the each user_id and with it I call another column id with Max function that will return max id for each user id and I have made temp table of both the column and then I will join that temp table with same table to get all column of related latest id

```
SELECT * FROM test_series_records AS tsr
INNER JOIN (SELECT user_id, MAX(id) AS id FROM test_series_records GROUP BY 
user_id) AS temp on temp.id = tsr.id;
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it